# Will a potentiometer let me adjust the volume on an RCA to 3.5mm headphone cable?

Tags: audio, potentiometer, rca, volume

I don't know a lot about EE, and this might not be the best place to ask, but I have a *really* basic question. I'm thinking about cutting an RCA to 3.5mm cable in half and inserting a pot for volume adjustment (it goes from TV to bluetooth transmitter). If that would work then what kind of pot would be best, and could I add another pot for right-channel adjustment? I was thinking that a concentric pot might be able to simplify things (one is better than two). I'd buy a premade cable that does what I want, but I don't think it exists. Any advice would be appreciated.

I'll draw a diagram and update my picture, if needed.

[image: RCA-3.5mm]

Answer (score 1):

Since humans perceive loudness logarithmically, it would be best to use a logarithmic trim pot to adjust volume. If you want to control two channels simultaneously and symmetrically, use a [two-gang logarithmic potentiometer](https://www.digikey.com/short/4c72q7).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want the right-channel to be a an adjustable fraction/percentage of the master volume, and I don't see how a two-gang pot can do that without additonial parts (I'd like to keep things as simple as possible).

Comment: In that case, use a one-gang log pot on the right channel and just let the left channel pass through.

Comment: You're right: That's probably the simplest way to do it. Controlling the right-channel is all I need to do. But then, I thought, why not add a master volume control?  And I don't think a two-gang pot will do what I want..

Comment: You could be right about using a logarithmic/audio trim pot, but I might not need it.. I use other headphones that have a linear (I think) slide control for volume, and those work fine. I guess my real question is: "Will one concentric potentiometer let me adjust both master volume and left-right balance? If so, which potentiometer should I use?"

Comment: You can certainly get away with a linear pot and it will work fine... you will just lose precision at low volumes and find that it jumps from zero to loud much more quickly than with a log pot, which is why parts marketed as "audio pots" and the knobs on a guitar are all log.

Comment: A concentric pot sounds like a good, compact answer! Plenty of cheap ones on eBay. If you want maximum audio quality (minimum noise) then a conductive plastic potentiometer is about as good as it gets, but it's probably overkill at 10x the cost...